# WPF binding at runtime not working

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mahapps.metro

Using .NET 4.7.1 WPF with MahApps 1.6.1.4. I'm binding the HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon like this:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
<Ellipse">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
</controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
```

In Design mode I can right click "Image" and go to the property in my ViewModel that is the UserControl.DataContext. As expected.

But in runtime this fails with this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Image' property not found on 'object' ''HamburgerMenuIconItem' (HashCode=44346036)'. BindingExpression:Path=Image; DataItem='HamburgerMenuIconItem' (HashCode=44346036); target element is 'ImageBrush' (HashCode=21345065); target property is 'ImageSource' (type 'ImageSource')
```

So at runtime it is trying to bind to a property in the "HamburgerMenuIconItem" or what? I can force the binding to the View code behind like this:

```
{Binding Path=Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}
```

Which works at runtime also, but I'd like the property in my ViewModel.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue is missing inheritance of the DataContext (but only at Runtime). The solution explained [here](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) solved my issue.